# vaadin4spring + application without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin4spring

I am trying to use vaadin4spring (https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring) to setup security for my Spring application. There is a clear example of how to do this on the author page, but the problem is that the example is using Spring Boot and my application is not. I managed to run the application but am not able to proceed with the login. It fails with the strange message that the JSON response from server is incorrect. This is my Configuration class for security:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy;
import org.vaadin.spring.annotation.EnableVaadinExtensions;
import org.vaadin.spring.http.HttpService;
import org.vaadin.spring.security.annotation.EnableVaadinSharedSecurity;
import org.vaadin.spring.security.config.VaadinSharedSecurityConfiguration;
import org.vaadin.spring.security.shared.VaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.vaadin.spring.security.shared.VaadinSessionClosingLogoutHandler;
import org.vaadin.spring.security.shared.VaadinUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.vaadin.spring.security.web.VaadinRedirectStrategy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableVaadinExtensions
@EnableVaadinSharedSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and().withUser("admin")
                .password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable(); // Use Vaadin's built-in CSRF protection instead
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**").anonymous().antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.httpBasic().disable();
        http.formLogin().disable();
        // Remember to add the VaadinSessionClosingLogoutHandler
        http.logout().addLogoutHandler(new VaadinSessionClosingLogoutHandler()).logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));
        // Instruct Spring Security to use the same RememberMeServices as Vaadin4Spring. Also remember the key.
        http.rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices()).key("myAppKey");
        // Instruct Spring Security to use the same authentication strategy as Vaadin4Spring
        http.sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/VAADIN/**");
    }

    /**
     * The {@link AuthenticationManager} must be available as a Spring bean for Vaadin4Spring.
     */
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * The {@link RememberMeServices} must be available as a Spring bean for Vaadin4Spring.
     */
    @Bean
    public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        return new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("myAppKey", userDetailsService());
    }

    /**
     * The {@link SessionAuthenticationStrategy} must be available as a Spring bean for Vaadin4Spring.
     */
    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean(name = VaadinSharedSecurityConfiguration.VAADIN_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS_HANDLER_BEAN)
    public VaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler vaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler(HttpService httpService,
                                                                          VaadinRedirectStrategy vaadinRedirectStrategy) {
        return new VaadinUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(httpService, vaadinRedirectStrategy, "/");
    }

}
```

I setup my application this way:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
import org.vaadin.spring.servlet.Vaadin4SpringServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class WebContextInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public WebContextInitializer() {
        super(WebConfig.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext) {

        registerVaadinServlet(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerVaadinServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("vaadinServlet", Vaadin4SpringServlet.class);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
        dispatcher.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Using [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance) (or similar) you can check the replies you get for your requests on the network tab. Try to see what JSON you're getting back from the server, perhaps you can figure out what's wrong.